# Javascript Function like Objects i.e. "$" can be used as a function e.g. $() as well as an object $

Tags: javascript

Questions in the title. I've always wondered and failed to find out from the jQuery source. How this is done.

To reiterate. In jQuery: how does the "$" become a function e.g."$()" as well as an object "$."

I can create it one way OR the other like so...

```
var $ = function(){
    return {each:function(){console.log("Word")}}
}
// $.each(); FAIL!
$().each(); // Word


var $ = {
    each:function(){console.log("Word")}
}
$.each(); // Word
//$().each(); FAIL!
```

Comment: In javascript, **functions are objects**. They are simply a special type of object which support interaction using a method-call syntax. Javascript's object/function unification makes possible a host of other features, like closures, currying, and higher-order methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with the basic function:

```
var $ = function(expr) { return $.select(expr); }
```

Then, add extra functionality to it:

```
$.select = function(expr)
{
    console.log("selecting " + expr);
    return $; // TODO: perform selection
};

$.each = function()
{
    console.log("Called $.each()");
};
```

You can see how this pattern is used in jQuery by looking at [the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js):

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
}

jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    init: function( selector, context ) {
        var match, elem, ret, doc;

        // Handle $(""), $(null), or $(undefined)
        if ( !selector ) {
            return this;
        }

        // contents of init() here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in javascript a function is an object.  you can create a function with properties, other functions (methods).  just write this up in Javascript and look at the type of `myfunc`

```
var myfunc = function() {
 //do stuff
}
```

when you look at the type of `myfunc` in Firebug you will see that the `myfunc` is an object.